# Express-session not persisting in navigators

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, express-session

I'm trying to make a backend for authentication using express and express-session, and I want to store a cookie so the second time that the user tries to log it won't be necessary to check the credentials. My problem is that I call to the endpoints with Postman for example it works, but when I do them with Brave, Chrome and others it doesn't and I don't think is a configuration problem of the navigator because in a private window it also doesn't work.

Here's the code from index.js:

```
const express = require("express");
const session = require("express-session");
const cors = require("cors"); // Importa el paquete cors
const controladorUsuarios = require("./contoladores/user.controller");
// Configuración de express-session

const PORT = 3001;

const app = express();
app.use(
  session({
    secret: "mi-secreto",
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: { secure: false, maxAge: 60000 }, // Porque no estoy usando https, sino -> true
  }))
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());



app.post("/iniciarSesion", async (req, res) => {
  console.log('Cookie:  ' + JSON.stringify(req.session.user))
  if (!req.session.user) {
    controladorUsuarios.comprobarCredenciales((errors, credencialesCorrectas, results) => {
      if (errors) {
        res
          .status(401)
          .send("Nombre de usuario y/o contraseña incorrectos: " + errors);
      } else {
        if (credencialesCorrectas === true) {
          req.session.user = results
          res
            .status(200)
            .send(
              "Credenciales correctas: " +
                JSON.stringify(req.body)
            );
        } else {
          console.log('Nombre de usuario y/o contraseña incorrectos')
          res
            .status(401)
            .send("Nombre de usuario y/o contraseña incorrectos");
        }
      }
    }, req.body);
  } else {
    console.log("Utilizando la cookie para el inicio de sesión")
    res
      .status(200)
      .send(
        "El usuario ya ha iniciado sesión: " + JSON.stringify(req.session)
      );
  }
});

app.post("/registrarUsuario", async (req, res) => {
  controladorUsuarios.registrarUsuario((errors, results) => {
    if (errors) {
      res
        .status(401)
        .send("No se ha podido registrar al usuario:    " + errors);
    } else {
      res
        .status(200)
        .send(
          "Usuario registrado correctamente:    " + JSON.stringify(results)
        );
    }
  }, req.body);
});

app.get('/prueba', async (req, res) => {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(req.session.user))
  res.status(200).send(JSON.stringify(req.session.user))
})

app.get("/tareas", async (req, res) => {
  if (req.session.user) {
    console.log("Usuario accediendo a sus tareas");
  } else {
    console.log("Usuario no identificado");
  }
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server listening on ${PORT}`);
});
```

This is what I get if I call 2 times: '/iniciarSesion' with Brave:

```
Cookie:  undefined
Cookie:  undefined
```

And this is what I get when I use Postman:

```
Cookie:  undefined
Cookie:  [{"id":1,"nombre":"admin","password":"admin"}]
Utilizando la cookie para el inicio de sesión
```

Which is supposed to be the normal output

Also, I'm using http not https, so that is why I set:

`cookie: { secure: false, maxAge: 60000 },`

I've been revising the network and this is what I get when I do fetch to '/iniciarSesion': [image]

So I see that there's a cookie that has been set
But looking at the application storage there's no cookies that had been stored: [image]

I don't find the issue, if someone can help it would be very helpful

Comment: `that I wrote below` there is no code below - what response (in the browser) do you get for the FIRST request, 401? 200? is it possible that `if (errors) {` is true?

Comment: when u check browser did it send cookie?

Comment: @JaromandaX I recieve a 200 code, sry for the below thing, I meant: “the code from above”

Comment: @SomeoneSpecial yes, I’ve been revising it and there’s a cookie in brave from my site but I don’t know why the code doesn’t use it

Comment: the request URL is `localhost:3001` ... you're looking at cookies for `localhost:3000` ... it may as well be a completely different server ... oh, it is - is the request from a form submission or from XMLHttpRequest/fetch - if the latter, I think you may need to set a flag with the request - `credentials: "include"` I believe for `fetch` ... or `withCredentials:true` for XMLHttpRequest

Comment: @JaromandaX it worked, it was for crossing origin without credentials. Thank u so much

Comment: Would've got that straight away if I had know the cross origin aspect :p